# gdb layer is not visible

Tags: qgis, layers

I am trying to open in my QGIS 3.4.10 a .dbg file that is containing a single layer from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vuowtebp9f1iud/LiMW_GIS%202015.gdb.zip?dl=0

After extracting it from the .zip, I drag&drop it into the layers list, but though it is checked, I cannot see anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to display the content on QGIS 3.16. I've also tested with QGIS 3.4. Both work on my machine. FYI, for 3.4, QGIS was asking me about the data projection contrary to 3.16

How I proceed to see the content

- download your file
- unzip the file
- drag and drop the **directory** `LiMW_GIS 2015.gdb` in QGIS
- see the result (below)

[image]

Except an install problem, I don't see where the issue could be as I'm unable to reproduce your issue.